# Where can I find the open source contribution result of the survey 2020 and above?

Tags: discussion, survey

In 2017, the survey covered the [open source participation](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#developer-profile-_-program-as-a-hobby):

> [image: 2017]

In 2018, the survey covered the [open source participation](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#developer-profile-_-contributing-to-open-source):

> [image: 2018]

In 2019, the survey covered the [open source participation](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-contributing-to-open-source):

> [image: 2019]

So here is my question, where can I find the open source contribution result of the survey 2020 and above? For example I try to search [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020) for the 2020 open source result without success. Was the question asked?

I cant find it for 2016 either, but I think that the question did not exist at that point.

Comment: How do you know that the question was asked in 2020?

Comment: I don't know that why I wrote "Was the question asked?" in the body. I presumed in the title that it is to show the main goal of my question. Since SO asked it three years in a row, I think that it is a self bet. Now since I cant find it, maybe it is because it was not asked. Note that English is not my first language, so feel free to edit my question to improve it.